# Why is my normal vector always blank? HLSL

Tags: vector, xna, shader, hlsl, lighting

I am trying to create a basic diffuse shader with HLSL, with [this rbwhitaker tutorial](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/diffuse-lighting-shader). The shader runs without errors and can display triangles, but it seems that the Normal input to the vertex shader is never given a value, which causes the diffuse lighting to break. I tested this by setting the output color to white, and then subtracting the normal, but there was never any variation in colors, it stayed white. My shader code is below.

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

float4x4 WorldInverseTranspose;

float3 DiffuseLightDirection = float3(1, 0, 0);
float4 DiffuseColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float DiffuseIntensity = 1.0;
float4 AmbientColor = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
float AmbientIntensity = 0.1;

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Normal : NORMAL0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection); 
    
    
    float4 normal = mul(input.Normal, WorldInverseTranspose);
    float lightIntensity = dot(normal, DiffuseLightDirection);
    output.Color = saturate(DiffuseColor * DiffuseIntensity * lightIntensity);;
    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
   return saturate(input.Color + AmbientColor * AmbientIntensity);
}

technique Diffuse
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I think it is probably because I don't directly pass the normal to the shader, but I don't know how to compute it if there isn't a built in way.